# Perform Remote Validation with .NET core

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

Something I thought was simple but apparently not, for a reason that is currently obscur to me.

I am trying to validate the e-mail address of a user who wants to register on my site.

For this, I use the attribute [Remote] that calls a method from another controller and does the checking.

Except that the input parameter of this method always arrives null, so it does not receive the email address entered by the user.

I saw that the name of the variable should be the same as that of my model and it is the case (at least I think ?!).

Do you have an idea?

**Model directly in RegistrationController**

```
public class InputModel
{
    [Remote("ValidateEmail", "Home", ErrorMessage = "This email his already used.")]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email *")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}



**Home Controller where the method is**



public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateEmail(string Email)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Email);

    bool result;

    if (user.UserName == null)
    {
        result = true;
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return Json(result);
}
```

**View**

```
            <div class="form-check-inline col-12">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                </div>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left:33%">
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Add your model reference code in the view please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `remote validation`, it will append the `Input.Email` as query string, but you bind the parameter with `(string Email)` which will not be able to bind.

Try to explictly bind the proeprty by `FromQuery`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateEmail([FromQuery(Name = "Input.Email")]string Email)
{
    bool result = false;
    return Json(result);
}
```